# How to remove author name from blog post url?

Tags: 7, uri

When a user publishes a blog post the user's name is included as part of
the blog link or url:

> www.example.com/blogs/**author**/post-name

What I want is that:

> www.example.com/blogs/post-name

**How can I remove that author name from the url?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be fix by using URL aliases in your drupal site. go to **admin/config/search/path/patterns** in that you can able to see text box as **Pattern for all Blog entry paths** in that change the pattern as **blogs/[node:title]** and use can able to use different tokens to change the patterns.

After configuring the pattern you need to update the url aliases in the content panel then only it will get the update to blog content type...

Answer (score 1):

For **Drupal 6**; you can go to **admin/build/path/pathauto** page and change URL alias pattern for Blog content type (under Node paths settings).

You can make it **blogs/[title-raw]** or anything else you want.

[image: http://tips.webdesign10.com/files/u1/pathauto-rules.png]

**Note**: The picture above shows how to do change URL pattern. But, the URL pattern isn't what you want. The URL here something like that: term/blog-post-13.html.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by changing URL alias pattern for "Pattern for all Blog paths" to "blogs/[title-raw]" here "admin/build/path/pathauto" in "Node paths" fieldset

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am new to Drupal. Can you explain some more clear.

Comment: i am unable to access the page. It is giving me 404 .